# Check all local partition letter and start encryption on each one

Tags: powershell

Does anyone have an idea how can I check all the local partitions(letters) on a remote host and start encryption on every partition with powershell. I was thinking something like, but what I did wrong? My code:

```
$disk=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '3'" | Select DeviceID

ForEach($letter in $disk){

Read-Host -Prompt “Criptam” + $letter + "?" 
$let = $letter + ":"
manage-bde.exe -on $let -recoverypassword -skiphardwaretest
```

Comment: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty DeviceID`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName Server_Name -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '3'" | ForEach {
  Read-Host -prompt ('Criptam' + $letter + '?')
  $letter = "$($_.DeviceId):"
  & "manage-bde.exe" -on $let -recoverypassword -skiphardwaretest
}
```

Or

```
$disk=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '3'" | Select -ExpandProperty DeviceID

ForEach($letter in $disk){

Read-Host -Prompt ("Criptam"+ $letter + "?")
$let = $letter + ":"
manage-bde.exe -on $let -recoverypassword -skiphardwaretest 
}
```

- Added -ComputerName parameter to specify the name of remote host in Get-WmiObject
- Piped output of Get-WmiObject to ForEach
- Fixed Read-Host part, the prompt string gets broken without parentheses
- Changed $let
- Used (&) operator to run manage-bed.exe

The biggest fault was that the Select-Object you got the list of drives not as an array and this could be done by -ExpandProperty which selects properties as array without header.